# Groovy sort a map

Tags: groovy

please can you help me with sorting a map

```
 def map = [
  [name:"Jerry", age: 42],
  [name:"Long", age: 25],
  [name:"Dustin", age: 29],
  [name:"Bin", age: 34]]

  map.each{entry -> println "$entry.name : $entry.age : $entry.city" }
```

gives me

```
Jerry : 42 : null
Long : 25 : null
Dustin : 29 : null
Bin : 34 : null
```

I want to sort this by age descending to get

```
Jerry : 42 : null
Bin : 34 : null
Dustin : 29 : null
Long : 25 : null

 sortedone = map.sort { a, b -> a.value <=> b.value }
```

does not work for me.
Please can you help?

Comment: Use `a.age` instead of `a.value`. the same for `b`

Comment: "does not work" is a not-so-great problem description.  Please add what does not work.

Comment: `map.sort{ it.age }` should do

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sort(Closure)` method:

```
def map = [
  [name:"Jerry", age: 42],
  [name:"Long", age: 25],
  [name:"Dustin", age: 29],
  [name:"Bin", age: 34]]

map.sort { -it.age }

println map

[[name:Jerry, age:42], [name:Bin, age:34], [name:Dustin, age:29], [name:Long, age:25]]
```